# measure defined in terms of an integral

Tags: lebesgue-integral, borel-measures

Here's a problem from a midterm I took 2 decades ago!  Let $A$ be a Borel measurable set on the real line and $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure. Define a measure $\mu(A)=\int_A f d\lambda$ where $f(x)=1/x^2$ for $x\ne 0$ and $f(0)=\infty$.

1. Is $\mu$ finite? $\sigma$-finite?

Now I know it's not finite, since if $A$ is any interval containing $0$ then the integral is infinite.  I'm not sure about $\sigma$-finite though. Any interval that does not contain $0$ will have finite measure, and there's a countable number of these to cover everything but $\{0\}$, so it seems to me that the answer depends on the following....

2. What is $\mu(\{0\})$?

Comment: @Surb Could you elaborate why that should imply that $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite? We can just choose another sequence of sets, e.g. $\{0\}\cup\{x\in \Bbb R : |x|\geq 1/n\}$

Answer (score 2):

$\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.  $$
\mathbb R = \{0\} \cup \bigcup_{n=2}^\infty [1/n,n] 
\cup \bigcup_{n=2}^\infty [-n,-1/n]
$$
and all those sets have finite measure.

Comment: But this only works if $\mu(\{0\})$ is finite, which I'm not sure of.

Comment: Look back at the definition of integration.  Yes, $\int_A f\;d\lambda = 0$ if $\lambda(A) = 0$.  Check it.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I was thrown off by the facts that

1. $f$ takes values on the extended reals and
2. $f\chi_A$ is not necessarily integrable

but I should have gone back to basics.
Here's my attempt at filling in the details:

Despite 1. and 2. above, $f\chi_A$ is still measurable for all Borel measurable sets $A$.  In particular, $f\chi_{\{0\}}$ is Borel measurable, and can be approximated by simple functions $s_n$ such that $0 \le s_n \le f\chi_{\{0\}}$ (take $s_n = n\chi_{\{0\}}$ for example).  Since the support of $s_n$ is a Borel set of measure $0$, $\int_{\mathbb{R}} s_n=0$ for all $n$, and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f\chi_{\{0\}} = sup \int_{\mathbb{R}} s_n=0$.  This shows that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$.